# How to create a new view or a copy of an existing view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have been developing an app to create your own notecards.  I seem to be stuck on how I would create a copy of a view so that the user can create as many cards as they want.  The name of the view I want to copy is main.

I also want to be able to save that view as a new view.  The purpose of this would be so I the user doesn't have to keep re-creating their cards.

I am very new to all of this so please if you have the chance to explain something please do.  I am currently coding all of this in swift.  If you have any questions feel free to comment.

Main problem:
-Need to be able to copy a UIview

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save a ViewController as a new view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466912/how-to-save-a-viewcontroller-as-a-new-view)

Comment: No I am asking how to save it once its cretaed on that one

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question. But if I understand it right then you do not need to create copys of the view controller. The view of the controller is just a visual representation of some date set. If you have multiple set's of the same type of data then you can reuse the same view for all of them. But I would need more information about your app to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Are you willing to help if I provide more info?

Comment: Yes, post some screenshots of what you already have. And let us see more code.